# How to update record onclick of button for particular user?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I am new in angular. I am using angular CLI 8.1.0. I have list of users in my sql table and every user have column "status". I listed list of users on mat table through rest api and php mysql. And after clicking any record it's corresponding details are showing on new page with the help of parameter of url. Now I have 2 buttons on my new page "approve" and "reject". when I click on approve the status column for that user should change from "pending" to "approve"(same for reject). My backend code is working fine on postman. But not able to achieve on angular

> approve.component.html

```
<button mat-stroked-button class="b1" (click)="approve()">Approve</button>
    <button mat-stroked-button class="b2" (click)="reject()">Reject</button>
```

> approve.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-approval',
  templateUrl: './approval.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./approval.component.css']
})
export class ApprovalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,private apiService:ApiService,private router:Router) { }

  id:any;
  result:any;

  ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.id=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    //console.log(this.id);

    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((queryParams:Params)=>{
      let vendorId=this.id;      
      this.apiService.getVendorById(vendorId)
      .subscribe(data=>{
        this.result = data[0];      

      });
    });
  }
  approve()
  {

    this.router.navigate(["/home/vendor-action"]);
  }
  reject()
  {
    this.router.navigate(["/home/vendor-action"]);
  }
}
```

> api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Users } from './users';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Displayvendor } from './adminpanel/home/vendor-action/displayvendor';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  redirectUrl:string;
  baseUrl:string="http://localhost/repos/Sportaz-repo/VaamozWeb/VaamozBusiness/RestApi/VaamozStore/AdminStore/angular_admin/php";
  @Output() getLoggedInName: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  private static URL = 'http://localhost/repos/Sportaz-repo/VaamozWeb/VaamozBusiness/RestApi/VaamozStore/AdminStore/angular_admin/php/index.php';

  constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient) { }

  getVendorById(data)
  {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost/repos/Sportaz-repo/VaamozWeb/VaamozBusiness/RestApi/VaamozStore/AdminStore/angular_admin/php/index.php?id='+data);
  }

  updateById(data)
  {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost/repos/Sportaz-repo/VaamozWeb/VaamozBusiness/RestApi/VaamozStore/AdminStore/angular_admin/php/index.php?id='+data);
  }
}
```

> index.php

```
<?php
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","angdb");

    $request=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    $data=array();
    switch($request)
    {
        case 'GET':
            response(getData());
            break;

        case 'PUT':
            response(updateData());

        default:
            #code...
            break;
    }

    function getData()
    {
        global $conn;

        if(@$_GET['id'])
        {
            @$id=$_GET['id'];

            $where="AND id=".$id;
        }
        else
        {
            $id=0;
            $where="";
        }


        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from vendor where status='pending' ".$where);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $data[]=array("id"=>$row['id'],"changeColumn"=>$row['changeColumn'],"type"=>$row['type'],"timestamp"=>$row['timestamp'],"status"=>$row['status'],"name"=>$row['name']);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function updateData()
    {
        global $conn;
        parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'),$_PUT);

        if(@$_GET['id'])
        {
            @$id=$_GET['id'];

            $where="where id=".$id;
        }
        else
        {
            $id=0;
            $where="";
        }

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"update vendor set status='".$_PUT['status']."'".$where);

        if($query==true)
        {
            $data[]=array("Message"=>"Updated");
        }
        else
        {
            $data[]=array("Message"=>"Not updated");
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function response($data)
    {
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are not passing any data to backend as well as not calling PUT method on the server to update the status.

Firstly, Fix your component so that it passes correct status code to service and wait for action to complete before redirecting to new page. For example,

```
async approve()
{
    await this.apiService.updateData(this.id, { status: 'Approve' });
    this.router.navigate([ "/home/vendor-action" ]);
}

async reject()
{
    await this.apiService.updateData(this.id, { status: 'Reject' });
    this.router.navigate([ "/home/vendor-action" ]);
}
```

Secondly, update you service's `updateData` method to allow pay load.

Comment: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)
error showing

Answer (score 0):

for both methods approve & reject you should call the REST API service by the id and the new status

for example

```
approve() {
    this.apiService.updateById(this.id, {status:'approve'})
    .subscribe((data:any)=> {
        if (data.Message == "Updated") { // check if the result is sucess then navigat to
            this.router.navigate(["/home/vendor-action"]);
        }
    });
}
reject() {
    this.apiService.updateById(this.id, {status:'reject'})
    .subscribe((data:any)=> {
        if (data.Message == "Updated") { // check if the result is sucess then navigat to
            this.router.navigate(["/home/vendor-action"]);
        }
    });
}
```

and edit also your service method to be like this

```
updateById(id,payload)
 {
    let url = `http://localhost/repos/Sportaz-repo/VaamozWeb/VaamozBusiness/RestApi/VaamozStore/AdminStore/angular_admin/php/index.php?id=${id}`
    return this.http.put(url, payload);
 }
```

or you can recieve it as a paramter in your php

```
updateById(id,obj) {
    let url = `http://localhost/repos/Sportaz-repo/VaamozWeb/VaamozBusiness/RestApi/VaamozStore/AdminStore/angular_admin/php/index.php?id=${id}`
    return this.httpClient.put(url, {}, {params: { status:obj.status } }  )
}
```

Comment: on approve method Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)
error is coming. and when i am removing 'approve' then on if condition "Property 'result' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)" error is showing

Comment: now only this error is showing Property 'result' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)

Comment: fir the first error , you have to change method `updateById` to accept 2 paramters or pass only one paramter as an object . and for the 2nd error change `data` to be `(data:any)` and this line only if condition to check before navigate and you can ignore it if no need for it

Comment: constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,private apiService:ApiService,private router:Router) { }

  id:any;
  data:any;
  result:any;
written but still same error

Comment: no , i mean data parameter for the observable , i updated the post , check it again

Comment: changed it but its not updating the data at backend

Comment: for updating data at backend side i have used PUT method in my php code. You can see my index.php code

Comment: the status column is empty instead of "approve"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209306/discussion-between-ahmed-el-sayed-and-manisha).